# I filed my 2015 taxes with 1040 using TurboTax, but I am F1 student. How should I file for amendment

Tags: united-states, f1-student-visa, form-1040x, amended-tax-return

I am on F1 Visa(International student). I have a W2 from my summer internship. I accidentally filed my taxes using TurboTax with 1040A, but I need to file with 1040NR. How should I file for amendment?

Answer (score 2):

File 1040X. According to the part of 1040X instructions dealing with [nonresident aliens](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040x/ch01.html#d0e535), you can use 1040X if you filed the wrong form and need to file the right form. You would only fill out some of the sections of the 1040X and fill out and attach the correct form (in your case, the 1040NR or 1040NR-EZ) to it.